# How to re-use Auth to register, authenticate as Rest Api in Web2py

Tags: python, web2py

I am really novice in both python and web2py. My project is using angularjs for front-end, and web2py for backend as Rest Service.

I have noticed that web2py has already developed the class `Auth` which is used for authentication and authorization. However, if I use Rest Api, I don't really know how to re-use this class on Rest API.

For example, I try to do ajax call to register new user:

```
 $http.post('/myapp/authentication/register', user)
```

The below code does not work at all:

```
def register():
    return dict(form=auth.register())
```

I have to naively insert into `auth_user` table in manual manner:

```
def register():
    username = request.vars.username
    password = request.vars.password
    email = request.vars.email

    row = db.auth_user(username=username)
    if not row:
        db.auth_user.insert(username=username, password=password, email=email)

    else:
        raise HTTP(409, 'username exists')
```

This method does work out to insert new user into `auth_user` table. But, when I try to use method `login_bare`:

```
 login_bare(self, username, password)
```

It's always failed for user registered by above method. Is there any way I need to work around on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
db.auth_user.insert(username=username, password=password, email=email)
```

Above you are inserting the plaintext password. However, by default the `db.auth_user.password` field has a `CRYPT()` validator that hashes the password, and the hash is what is checked upon login. Typically the field validators (including the password field's `CRYPT` validator) are run when the form is submitted and processed (which doesn't happen in this case because you are not using a web2py form to submit the registration). However, you can run the validators as follows:

```
db.auth_user.validate_and_insert(username=username, password=password,
                                 email=email)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are creating a user record in the auth tables, good. But where are you logging in the user?  The auth model you're using is basically what a user does in UI -- first register, later logs in with user ID and password.

This style of authorization isn't ideal for REST clients for several reasons, one of which is typical REST clients don't behave like browsers, don't maintain cookies, and thus have no way to maintain sessions. You could require your REST clients to maintain cookies, but that's odd.

I'd recommend using an authorization framework that's built for REST. We've had good results with 3Scale. This gives you a way to define users and their privileges; provides a portal where the user manages their account (e.g. can re-issue keys); and even access API doco if you choose to put it there.

If you don't favor that approach, consider doing what Amazon does -- issue public and private keys per user, and establish a protocol for how the client must sign each request. You can probably crib a solution for that from open-source AWS tools.

In short, you can probably find a way to make the user auth framework function for REST but you will have better results if you don't.